# How to Build a menu similar to the Materialize Horizontal FAB?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

- Materialize **Horizontal FAB example**: http://materializecss.com/buttons.html
- My site: http://converte.co/site/

I started riding my site using Materialize but now I want to migrate to Bootstrap.

I'll use the Starter template bootstrap as a base to build my website.

What is the easiest way to set up a similar menu to that the Materialize using HTML and CSS only, and keep the same effects?

Comment: There is no easy way to explain it. I think Bootstrap doesn't have that kind of menu pre-built so you need to write it by your own. See how the code works on Material Design and try to duplicate it by yourself. Is the best way to learn it.

Comment: Thank @SandrinaPereira! I will open the CSS and JavaScript Materialize and try to understand it.

Comment: A tip about hover effect: The "childrens" of the menu have position absolute, opacitiy 0 to opacity 1. I think that's a good way to start. And you can do it only with css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Material design in Bootstrap [(you can find it on Github)](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/)

You can create the menu in pure CSS, Here is an example:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div style="margin-left:25%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">
  <h2>Fixed Full-height Side Nav</h2>
  <h3>Try to scroll this area, and see how the sidenav sticks to the page</h3>
  <p>Notice that this div element has a left margin of 25%. This is because the side navigation is set to 25% width. If you remove the margin, the sidenav will overlay/sit on top of this div.</p>
  <p>Also notice that we have set overflow:auto to sidenav. This will add a scrollbar when the sidenav is too long (for example if it has over 50 links inside of it).</p>
  <p>Some text..</p>
  <p>Some text..</p>
  <p>Some text..</p>
  <p>Some text..</p>
  <p>Some text..</p>
  <p>Some text..</p>
  <p>Some text..</p>
</div>
```

[code from W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp)

You can show elements hidden using **display: none**, you can use Jquery function .toggle() to show it.
Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.show > a").click(function(){
        $("li.hide").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li:nth-child(2)
{
  display: none;
  background: #4CAF50;
  padding: 10px;
}
li a:active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="show">
    <a href="#">Click me to show.</a>
  </li>
  <li class="hide">
    This is an hidden element
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This structure is simple. What is difficult for me is this effect "hover" that shows what is hidden with a transition effect. I'll keep searching. Thank you!

Comment: I will continue to use Materialize because it is one of the main framework "Mobile First". I will not use your solution, but anyway, thank you!

Comment: @PauloKenobi Ok, Have a nice day :)